# BQ2407x Li-Ion charging circuit, what if Vin is disconnected?

Tags: battery-charging, texas-instruments

We will use a Texas Instruments BQ24072 in our power board to monitor the battery.

-PoE or solar will charge
-Most of the time, circuit will work on battery.

When disconnection the Vin, one would assume the battery takes over.

datasheet p3 Vin voltage range between 4.35V and 26 V
datasheet p4 UVLO Undervoltage lock-out VIN: typical  3.3 V

This would suggest that everything stops working when Vin is too low.

[Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24072.pdf)

Answer:
ok, datasheet p16, everything shuts down but battery is "connected" to out

UNDERVOLTAGE LOCKOUT (UVLO)

The bq2407X family remains in power down mode when the input voltage at the IN pin is below the undervoltage
threshold (UVLO).
During the power down mode the host commands at the control inputs (CE, EN1 and EN2) are ignored. The Q1
FET connected between IN and OUT pins is off, and the status outputs CHG and PGOOD are high impedance.
**The Q2 FET that connects BAT to OUT is ON.** (If SYSOFF is high, Q2 is off). During power down mode, the
VOUT(SC2) circuitry is active and monitors for overload conditions on OUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BQ2407x Li-Ion charging circuit, what if Vin is disconnected?

The IC draws 6.5 uA maximum from the battery.

See datasheet "quiescent current" on page 4

[image]

Comment: My concern was that the load would not be supplied when Vin was disconnected, but that assumption was incorrect. But, I must admit, this IS the right answer to the question if no load is present!